# How to map domain to EC2 and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I want to host website on **S3 and application server on EC2**.

I have a domain name from names cheap and added a 'A' record with '@' host pointing to elastic IP associated with my EC2 instance.

Also on EC2 instance i have tomcat running on port `8080`. When i send request to `mydomain.com:8080/webservice` its working as expected. This webservice is for mobile applications nothing to do with static site, which i want to host on S3.

Now I want to configure `mydomain.com` to S3 bucket. how do i do that?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the solution was to create two DNS records

1)CNAME "WWW" record to point www.mydomain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

2)A Record "api" to ip address. This allows api.mydomain.com to point to elastic ip with point to ec2 instance

Comment: Was thinking along the same lines. Brilliant question, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Example: Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) for the steps setting up a custom domain for a static website on S3.

Comment: My concern is not just pointing domain to S3. i want request on port 8080 to continue to go to elastic ip, which is mapped to ec2 instance. i want post 80 ie "mydomain.com to point to S3 bucket

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an A record on namecheap that points to an S3 bucket. You have to use a CNAME record to point to an S3 bucket. You can't use a CNAME record for a root domain like "mydomain.com". You could setup a CNAME record on namecheap that points "www.mydomain.com" to your S3 bucket.

If you need to point the root of your domain (mydomain.com) to S3 you will have to move your DNS hosting to Route53 so that you can use an alias record, as detailed [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/root-domain-website-hosting-for-amazon-s3/).

Comment: Thanks, i am open to use Route53, but how to i ensure mydomain.com:8080 maps to elastic ip addess and mydomain.com map to S3 bucket.
If i follow steps above  would all traffic not end up on S3?

Comment: I missed the part where you are using the same domain name for both services. You can't do that without placing something in front of both of those services, like Nginx, that could then perform the routing based on the port. A domain name has to point to a single place. The port is not used in DNS routing. If the service on the EC2 server is just an API for a mobile app, why does it need to be mydomain.com? Why can't it be something like api.mydomain.com?

Comment: Thanks i am open to using api.mydomain.com to point to elastic ip address and mydomain.com to point to static s3. How would i go about doing it, without Nginx. the simpler the better.

 I just cant use [ip4] address for ec2 as apple wont allow that in the apps, hence need of domain name for static site and api.

Comment: Just create a new A record for api.mydomain.com, and point it to the elastic IP. For pointing mydomain.com to S3 you will still need to move your DNS to Route53 though.

Answer (score 1):

An apex record only supports A records which provide an IP address. If you use Route 53 to provide your DNS, you can set up an alias to a bucket, load balancer or other AWS services which will internally map to IP addresses.

The alias system only works with Route 53, you cannot do this with any other DNS provider.